# If the integral of the product of t and phi(t) converges, does the random variable have continuous density?

Tags: probability

If $\int|t\varphi(t)|\mathrm{d}t < \infty$, where $\varphi(t)$ is the characteristic function of a random variable $X$, does $X$ have continuous density?

My current thinking is: not necessarily. Multiplying by $t$ might remove a singularity from $\varphi(t)$. If that were so, then there may be an example of $\int|\varphi(t)|\mathrm{d}t = \infty$ and so $X$ wouldn't necessarily have continuous density.

But I can't think of a characteristic function that a) has a singularity at zero and b) when the absolute value of the product of it and $t$ is the integrand, the integral converges.

Is the question's answer actually 'yes'?

Comment: A characteristic function is (uniformly) continuous.

Comment: Thi is a direct consequence of the in inversion theorem for the Fourier transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\infty>\int_{R}|t|\varphi(t)|dt>\int_{|t|>1}|\varphi(t)|dt.$$ Furthermore $\int_{|t|<1}|\varphi(t)|dt<\infty$ since $\varphi$ is continuous. As a result $\int_R|\varphi(t)|dt<\infty\Rightarrow f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_Re^{-ixt}\varphi(t)dt$ exists and is continuous.